# changing the signup button url in WPMU/Buddypress

Tags: buddypress, user-registration

the default sign up button now points to: 
http://www.hoopinstructors.com/register/

I need to change the url so that it points to the real sign up page.

I looked at register.php, but I don't know php well enough to figure out how to do it. I searched for the url with firebug, but am still unclear on where exactly I can find - and change - the url that the button points to.

thanks,
Terri

Comment: What is *the **real** sign up page*?

Answer (score 2):

you need to look into the sourcecode and find the place where that link is created. I do not know WPMU/Buddypress specifically enough that I can answer this question out of my head, but basically you'll have the following options:

- Change the address in the sourcecode - That's normally the easiest way to do, but you must redo this after every update.
- Find a hook you can add your own filter function so to change the address on the fly.
- Or this is a theme issue so you can hack the theme.

Firebug can help a bit to analyze what's going on, but it's only in the browser. Changes need to be made on the server side so you should have at least some PHP and Wordpress experience.

Or to [find a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) that does the job and you're lucky. But I'm not aware of such.

Comment: Hi hakre: 

thanks so much - it's really helpful to have the options laid out that way. I'm going to try each option one at time and see what I can do.

Terri

Answer (score 1):

BuddyPress employs a different signup/registration process (creation steps, xprofile fields, avatar, account activation email, etc)

You could either create a child theme for registration/register.php and make the appropriated edits for your needs. Hook into the actions to add more content or create additional steps.

Or copy some of the source code which is required by BuddyPress
http://buddypress.org/community/groups/how-to-and-troubleshooting/forum/topic/modifying-customising-the-registration-process/#post-71966